# Проверить и обновить значение у NumericUpDown после каждого введенного с клавиатуры символа

Tags: c#, winforms

Пользователь вводит число в NumericUpDown с клавиатуры, но проверка этого числа на соответствие нижней и верхней границам происходит только после смены фокуса с numeric'а. Как я могу совершать эту встроенную проверку после каждого введенного символа?

Я хотел бы написать что-то вроде:

```
private void numericUpDown1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
                ((NumericUpDown)sender).ValidateEditText();
        }
```

Но метод ValidateEditText() защищенный, а не публичный.

Comment: Откажитесь от таких проверок. Они только мешают пользователю. Во когда фокус меняется, тогда и нужно проверять итоговое значение.

Comment: Юзер может вставить значение с помощью мышки. Упс, ваш метод обойдён.

Comment: А почему они могут помешать? В моем конкретном случае ограничение на максимальное значение всего 20, и если пользователь начинает вводить миллионы, то мне хотелось бы, чтобы он сразу увидел, что максимальное значение он никак не превысит.

Comment: Потому что распространённый и привычный способ работы - это когда юзер копирует значение откуда-то, захватывая при этом лишние символы и вставляет грязное значение в поле ввода. Потом по месту удаляет лишнее. А если вы и вставки ему ограничите и прочие драконовские меры предпримите, то кому это понравится?

Comment: Но если вам очень хочется, то используйте событие `TextChanged`.

Comment: Например, насколько я знаю, сейчас считается хорошим тоном при регистрации на различных ресурсах проверять ник регистрируемого пользователя на "занятость" сразу после его написания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `NumericUpDown` есть метод [Validate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.validate?System_Windows_Forms_ContainerControl_Validate=&view=netcore-3.1), его и надо вызывать.

Так как пользователь может изменять значения не только с клавиатуры, но и с помощью мышки, то лучше обрабатывать событие `TextChanged`. Кстати, в дизайнере оно скрыто у этого контрола. Поэтому сделаем это вручную, например, в событии `Load` формы.

```
numericUpDown1.TextChanged += NumericUpDown1_TextChanged;
```

Код в обработчике события:

```
private void NumericUpDown1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (numericUpDown1.Value < numericUpDown1.Minimum ||
        numericUpDown1.Value > numericUpDown1.Maximum)
        numericUpDown1.Validate();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение